# How can you find points in regions of space quickly

Tags: algorithm, math

Consider 5 dimensional space which has been partitioned by at least two planes  which go through the origin.  If there are `n` planes then the number of distinct pyramidal regions this creates is exactly [`n^4/24-n^3/4+(23 n^2)/24-(3 n)/4+1`](http://www.austms.org.au/Gazette/2006/Sep06/HoZ.pdf) as long as they are in "general position", a term I make specific below.

A hyperplane through the origin can be defined by a single vector starting at the origin which is orthogonal to the plane.  The hyperplanes are in general position if no three of the vectors defining the hyperplanes are coplanar.

> How can I find one point per pyramidal region efficiently in 5 dimensional space?   That is
>   to return `k` points in 5d space,
>   each of which is in a different pyramidal region.  The value `k` will be part of the input.

My naive attempt so far just picks points uniformly at random on the surface of a hypersphere using (in Python)

```
def points_on_sphere(dim, N, norm=numpy.random.normal):
    """
    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Generating_random_points
    """
    normal_deviates = norm(size=(N, dim))
    radius = numpy.sqrt((normal_deviates ** 2).sum(axis=0))
    points = normal_deviates / radius
    return points
```

And then chooses a subset so that each one is in a different region. I can verify that the points are really all in different pyramidal regions using the following code.

```
def all_in_distinct_pyramidal_regions(testpoints, hyperplanes):
    signs = numpy.sign(numpy.inner(testpoints, hyperplanes))
    return (len(set(map(tuple,signs)))==len(signs))
```

Here is a picture of 4 planes in 3d with 14 points, one in each region (because 5d was hard to draw), one in each of the pyramidal regions created by the planes.

[image]

> Is there an algorithm that works in 5 dimensional space to find `k` points, each in different pyramidal
>   regions and takes anything like O(nk) time?

I have noticed that the pyramidal regions are convex. Convex spaces are closed under addition and in particular it seems that if you knew the hyperplanes that formed the border of a region you could potentially find a point inside the region by averaging points on the hyperplanes. However, I am not sure how to turn this observation into a full efficient algorithm.

Comment: You're almost there.  Find the points generated by intersections of all combinations of 5 planes (or 3 in your 3d example).  Then add 10 additional (6 in 3d) planes (actually you can get away with 6 (4 in 3d), but the 10 can be normal to the axes, which probably simplifies things) that form a closed region around these points.  Now identify the vertices of each closed convex region formed by all the planes.  A halfspace intersection algorithm is certainly one way to do this.  There's likely to be be better ideas.  Average the vertices of these closed regions to get the desired points.

Comment: @Gene There are `n` hyperplanes in my problem so do you mean all intersections of all combinations of `n` hyperplanes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to dig up a Python library for linear programming, then here's an approach that's easy to implement and reasonably efficient (time `O(poly(n) k)`). It's similar to the one that Gene proposed.

Let `v1, ..., vm in R^5 \ 0` be normal vectors for some of the planes. To find a point in the intersection of their positive halfspaces, solve the linear program

```
maximize z
subject to
v1 . x - z >= 0
...
vm . x - z >= 0
x in [-1, 1]^5
z in R,
```

in variables `x, z`, where `.` denotes dot product. If `z > 0` in the optimal solution, then the point `x` is in the intersection of the positive halfspaces.

To find one point in each region, enumerate recursively all vectors of length `n` containing entries `±1`, with the following pruning. We interpret the entries of the vector as choosing the positive or negative halfspace of each normal vector. If the LP with a subset of constraints corresponding to the current prefix is infeasible, then prune the recursion. In Pythonish pseudocode:

```
def find_points(normals, prefix=()):
    "solve the LP with normals [sign * normals[i] for i, sign in enumerate(prefix)]"
    if "the LP is infeasible": pass
    elif len(normals) == len(prefix): yield x
    else:
        for point in find_points(normals, prefix + (1,)):  # or yield from
            yield point
        for point in find_points(normals, prefix + (-1,)):
            yield point
```

Thanks to the pruning, the number of internal nodes of the recursion tree is at most `n` times the number of regions, so this is **not at all exponential**.

The bottleneck of this approach is almost certainly solving the linear programs. Since we add constraints one at a time, if your LP solver supports it, specify the dual simplex algorithm and reuse the previous dual solution as the starting basis.

Comment: Thank you for this. Strictly speaking LP solving is unlikely to be poly time is it for whatever library I can find?

Comment: @user2179021 The worst case of simplex is exponential, but it rarely happens in practice. From the theoretical point of view, there are poly-time algorithms for LP in constant dimensions (but you'd likely have to implement them yourself).

Comment: Rightm thank you. Do you think there is a version of Gene's (and your) idea that doesn't rely on LP solving that can be work more quickly?

Comment: @user2179021 Seems tricky. Just testing whether an intersection of halfspaces is empty is equivalent to LP without an objective (which is sort of equivalent to LP with an objective, by using binary search with an extra constraint replacing the objective).

Comment: Gene's sketched algorithm didn't seem to require LP solving did it? Or have I missed some crucial detail that would be needed to actually implement it?

Comment: @user2179021 It's likely to be in the unspecified halfspace intersection algorithm.

Comment: @user2179021 If finding an LP library is too much trouble, you could try a homebrew barrier method.

Comment: Apparently intersecting half spaces and computing the convex hull are equivalent. http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3351&context=compsci

Comment: @user2179021 Computing the intersection is roughly at least as hard (time-wise) as testing whether it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a quadkey. Translate the points to a binary and concatenate it. Then sort the points. You can verify the upper bounds with the mostsignificant bits. You can find a source code from Microsoft Bing Maps:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx.